# Pod keeps restarting and is in a CrashLoopBackOff state

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

One of our pods won't start and is constantly restarting and is in a CrashLoopBackOff state:

NAME                                                        READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE

```
quasar-api-staging-14c385ccaff2519688add0c2cb0144b2-3r7v4   0/1      
CrashLoopBackOff   72         5h
```

Describing the pod looks this (just the events):

FirstSeen   LastSeen    Count   From                        SubobjectPath               Reason  Message

```
  57m       57m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Created Created with docker id 7515ced7f49c
  57m       57m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Started Started with docker id 7515ced7f49c
  52m       52m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Created Created with docker id 2efe8885ad49
  52m       52m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Started Started with docker id 2efe8885ad49
  46m       46m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Created Created with docker id a4361ebc3c06
  46m       46m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Started Started with docker id a4361ebc3c06
  41m       41m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Started Started with docker id 99bc3a8b01ad
  41m       41m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Created Created with docker id 99bc3a8b01ad
  36m       36m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Created Created with docker id 3e873c664cde
  36m       36m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Started Started with docker id 3e873c664cde
  31m       31m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Started Started with docker id 97680dac2e12
  31m       31m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Created Created with docker id 97680dac2e12
  26m       26m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Created Created with docker id 42ef4b0eea73
  26m       26m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Started Started with docker id 42ef4b0eea73
  21m       21m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Started Started with docker id 7dbd65668733
  21m       21m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Created Created with docker id 7dbd65668733
  15m       15m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Created Created with docker id d372cb279fff
  15m       15m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Started Started with docker id d372cb279fff
  10m       10m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Started Started with docker id bc7f5a0fe5d4
  10m       10m     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Created Created with docker id bc7f5a0fe5d4
  5m        5m      1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Created Created with docker id b545a71af1d2
  5m        5m      1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Started Started with docker id b545a71af1d2
  3h        25s     43  {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Pulled  Container image "us.gcr.io/skywatch-app/quasar-api-staging:15.0" already present on machine
  25s       25s     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Started Started with docker id 3e4087281881
  25s       25s     1   {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Created Created with docker id 3e4087281881
  3h        5s      1143    {kubelet gke-skywatch-cf86c224-node-21bm}   spec.containers{quasar-api-staging} Backoff Back-off restarting failed docker container
```

The log for the pod doesn't show much either:

```
Pod "quasar-api-staging-14c385ccaff2519688add0c2cb0144b2-3r7v4" in namespace "default": container "quasar-api-staging" is in waiting state.
```

I've been able to run the pod locally, and it seems to work. I'm not sure what else to check or try. Any help or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

You might try running `kubectl logs <podid> --previous` to see the logs from the previous instance of the container.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, and it gave me the following:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/skywatch/tornado/app.py", line 103, in <module>
    rx_cassandra = config['rx_cassandra']
KeyError: 'rx_cassandra'
** [Bugsnag] Notifying https://notify.bugsnag.com of exception`

How helpful would that be, if it's from the previous instance of when the pod ran successfully? 
FYI. The cassandra config is read from the config file as part of the build - it's a .json file with configuration information. Nothing has changed there, so  doubt that's what causing the issue.

Comment: It looks like it's missing some key from the json file? I really couldn't say. It may be indirectly related to Kubernetes but not directly.

Comment: $ kubectl logs -p <pod name> also works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but one that I would have wanted to find thirty minutes ago.

In my case the reason was that the node had an docker image on disk of a faulty version tagged latest.

My solution was to remove the faulty image from the node instance:

```
docker rmi faulty:latest
```